# Android Application freezs when calling Http Get function

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app reads xml from site. I have this code to get xml content.

```
public String getPage(String url){
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String data = null;
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI website = new URI(url);
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String l = "";
                String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                    sb.append(l + nl);
                }
                in.close();
                data = sb.toString();

                return data;        
            } finally{
                if (in != null){
                    try{
                        in.close();
                        return data;
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //return e.toString();
            return "No Internet Connection";
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and I am calling it from this

```
public void axtarHandler_run(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                TextView axtarish_key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.axtarish_key);
                String netice;
                try {
                    netice = getPage("http://somedomain.com/search.php?query="+URLEncoder.encode((String) axtarish_key.getText().toString(),"UTF-8"));
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    String xml = netice; // getting XML from URL
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                    final NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
                    // looping through all song nodes <song>
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        songsList.add(map);
                    }

                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(parentActivity, songsList, R.layout.list_row);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    // Click event for single list row
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(position);
                            String music_id = parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID);
                            String music_name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE);
                            parentActivity.play_music_forsearch(Integer.toString(position), music_id, music_name);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
        });
    }
```

But application freezes for some time when this method is called. how to be? How to do this on background?

Comment: sorry for blah blah blah

Comment: are u putting getPage in AsyncTask?

Comment: you should use a thread or asynctask for network related operation

Comment: Actually I am surprised it doesn't throw you a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: dude he is using Strict Mode policy to avoid that.

Comment: @user2012 Dude, he shouldn't: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html Most notably: "StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident ... StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread ..."

Comment: @BartFriederichs: yep thats what I mentioned in my answer.Strict Mode is strictly for developing phase.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

You then can make a request by:

```
 new RequestTask().execute("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: then but my xml parser won't wait until that task ends

Comment: onPostExecute you wl find the result string

Answer (score 0):

You are running it on the UI thread. Don't do that. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says you are running network related operation in the Main UI with `Strict Mode` policy.Which is strongly recommended not to do.use `AsynTask` to do this task.